# Between and Like in same where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to execute a query using Oracle `SQL` but I get an error. I wan to return a value based on the range of the parameters entered. See my example query below:

```
select column1, column2, column3
from table_name
where column1 between like '1234%' and like '1239%
```

The datatype for `column1` is `varchar2`.

Comment: What is the use of such a query? What values does that column have and what results do you expect?

Comment: For future reference please specify the error you get, including the ORA-00000 number (although in this case it's easy to see what's wrong with your query).

Comment: Why do you store numeric values in a varchar column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of like use SUBSTR():

```
select column1, column2, column3
from table_name
where substr(column1,4) between  '1234' and '1239'
/
```

Also, you may wish to cast the strings to numbers, to ensure you get the correct behaviour, although that depends on your data.

```
where to_number(substr(column1,4)) between  1234 and 1239
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this does what you want:

```
where column1 >= '1234' and
      column1 < '1240'
```

This more index-friendly, so it can use an index on `column1` -- which is an advantage of regular expressions.